# Pip install - do downloaded whl files persist & take disk space?

Tags: python, pip

While installing packages with `pip` in python, it downloads and installs a whl file, e.g. following file for pyqt5:

```
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d4/bf/d884da8e2f7096d201c891d515eb6813a8e85df5eb6f5e12e867bf1d831c/PyQt5-5.11.3-5.11.2-cp35.cp36.cp37.cp38-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
```

After installation, does this file persist on disc and take space?

If so, can it be removed to free space on disk?

Also, is there a link regarding this anywhere in documentations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it does. The wheels are stored at pip's caching folder. The location can be overriden via the `--cache-dir` parameter.

The default location for the cache directory depends on the Operating System:

> Unix
>
> ~/.cache/pip and it respects the XDG_CACHE_HOME directory.
>
> macOS
>
> ~/Library/Caches/pip.
>
> Windows
>   CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA>\pip\Cache

More information is available here: https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install/#caching

Comment: Wow. My `~/.cache/pip` is 1.1Gb in size. Can I safely remove its contents, which are in 2 folders: `http` and `wheels` and many subfolders?

Comment: Cleanup old files (older than half a year): `find ~/.cache/pip/ -type f -mtime +180 -delete`; adapt the period for your taste. And yes, you can safely delete anything and everything there including the entire `~/.cache/pip`.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of `PyQt5`, the 117.8MB installation file is cached in the `http` directory of the pip cache, which [Ramiro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54043403/1247781) includes the location of. You can safely remove both the `http` and `wheels` directories.

You can disable caching on future installations via the `--no-cache-dir` command line option ([source](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#caching)).

Comment: I am not clear regarding `deleting your existing cache`. Can I delete all contents of `~/.cache/pip` safely?

Comment: @rnso Built files are stored elsewhere so you can safely delete the contents of `~/.cache/pip`. I just tested it with PyQt5 to be sure; I deleted the `http` and `wheels` directories from the cache. I've updated my answer as well.